# How can I make an automatic PayPal buy button?

Tags: php, paypal

I want my PHP web application to have the ability to save the user's PayPal details in their user account.

When they go to purchase items, rather than going through the standard PayPal form, it will automatically grab the user's PayPal details from their user account, and make the payment directly from my website. There is definitely a way to do this, as I have seen this feature on sites such as Freelancer.com

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You need a paypal pro account to do that. https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Comment: Is it easy to implement?

Comment: they give you a tutorial on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need Payments Pro for that.  That would only be if you want to do it with direct credit cards.  What you're after in general is called [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/), and when done with [PayPal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) it uses [Billing Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#id094TB0Y0J5Z__id094TB4003HS).

You'll use Express Checkout and/or Payments Pro (optional) to process an original authorization or sale transaction.  Then, you can send that ID you get back in that original transaction along with a new amount in the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API and that new amount will be instantly processed without any redirection or further authorization required.

Comment: I was watching your YouTube video on PayPal pro only a couple of hours ago, and now you're here wow lol

Comment: So just to confirm so I understand:

1. Using a billing agreement, users can save their PayPal details on my web app

2. When users go to purchase an item, I use the DoReferenceTransaction to grab the details of this billing agreement in order to make an automatic payment. This also won't have any redirection to a PayPal form or confirmation etc.

Comment: You would use Express Checkout to create the billing agreement.  That would give you back a billing agreement ID which you would save with your customer data in your database.  Then when you need to charge a customer you would pull their billing agreement ID so you can pass it into DoReferenceTransaction.

Comment: So by using express checkout to create the billing agreement, does that mean that the user has to buy something on my store at least once? Or do you use express checkout in order to go through the process to create the billing agreement, which will then allow them to buy products?

Comment: If they are in the process of actually buying something then you can add the billing agreement to that order.  If all you need is the billing agreement then you would call SetExpressCheckout and GetExpressCheckoutDetails like normal, but then instead of finishing off with DoExpressCheckoutPayment you would use [CreateBillingAgreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateBillingAgreement_API_Operation_NVP/).